# URLError in Python [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

Tags: python

I just want to try to connect to a website with Python but I have an error.
Here my code :

```
 import urllib.request
 with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
 html = response.read()
```

And here the error :

```
  URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Someone know how to solve this ? I found some topics about this but any solutions solve the problem.
Thx for advance !

Comment: check if you can open the same url in browser

Comment: yes it work on my browser (Chrome)